# sql order by not working with group by only

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table stock activity where i have multiple records attached with single item_id. note item_id is playing foreign key role here in stock activity table . so actually i am tracking the item(in,out) of inventory. now i want to retrieve the last record activity stored in the table. i have written query which is supposed to be returning the last record from the table but it is returning the first record ..

Columns are :
activity_id pk
item_id fk
balance int(11)

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(item_id),balance
FROM `stock_activity` 
GROUP BY (item_id)
ORDER BY(activity_id) DESC
```

Comment: What are you expecting the `GROUP BY` to do?  You aren't running any aggregates over your data.  Also, please don't post pictures of queries.  Paste the contents of the queries into your question as text.

Comment: i just want a single record means one last row for one item

Comment: you can see in the second last record where i have 2 records so i use order by to get only one record not duplicated item records

Comment: well the problem is i dont understand why people putting down votes instead of telling me that your question is not clear please elaborate etc but they love putting down votes only cause thy dont understand

Comment: Please read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i think i have elaborated my question well i did my effort and i am old member of this community @TomH thanks for suggestion

Comment: plus i thought it would be cleaner through picture i can post my code right now but it would be bit difficult to understand than if i dont post schema here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember if a column that doesn't belongs to the grouping key is being referenced without any sort of aggregation so such statement is impossible.
So remember a little formula to came our this problem.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
     SELECT * FROM `table`
     ORDER BY AnotherColumn
    ) t1
    GROUP BY SomeColumn
    ;
```

Modify your query like this and hope it will work fine!!!.

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT(item_id),balance
FROM `stock_activity` 

ORDER BY(activity_id) DESC
) t1
GROUP BY (item_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem folks have an issue with. you want the GROUPWISE MAXIMUM (or MINIMUM) of a column. Fortunately such an example exists right in the [tutorial section of the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)